# How to add OpenLayers map to ExtJs panel?

Tags: extjs, openlayers, extjs6

When I try to add `OpenLayers` map to `ExtJS` panel, I see some strange behaviour. The scale of the map becomes too big and of poor quality. In the browser console I see that only two png images are loaded, whereas when I do not use ExtJS and just render the map to a div component, then a dozen of images are loaded. So, this is the way I do it it now:

```
{
        region:'center',
        layout:'fit',
        title:'Map',
        xtype:'panel',
        html:'<div id="map"></div>',
        listeners:{
                render:function(){                                          
                    var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
                        source: new ol.source.OSM()
                    });
                    var moscow = ol.proj.transform([44.49,56.18], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
                    var view = new ol.View({
                      center: moscow,
                      zoom: 1
                    });
                    var map = new ol.Map({
                      target: 'map'
                    });
                    map.addLayer(osmLayer);
                    map.setView(view);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That problem sounds really interesting. Do you have a fiddle for me?

Comment: Yes, sure. Please, have a look at https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13kv

Comment: It seems like there is a solution to this problem - https://gist.github.com/tuxite/9954263 . And the main idea is to add resize renderer.

Answer (score 3):

I think, I found even a better way to implement this task (better than in [this](http://%20gist.github.com/tuxite/9954263) example). So, this is how I do it now:

```
{
    region:'center',
    layout:'fit',
    title:'Map',
    xtype:'panel',
    listeners:{
        afterrender:function(){

            var me = this,

            osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }),

            city = ol.proj.transform([44.49, 56.18], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),

            view = new ol.View({
              center: city,
              zoom: 6
            });

            this.map = new ol.Map({
                target: me.body.dom.id,
                renderer: 'canvas',
                layers: [osmLayer],
                view: view
            });  

        },
        resize: function () {
            this.map.updateSize();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tested on Ext 7 modern kit. Just add inline css in div tag.**

```
        region:'center',
        layout:'fit',
        title:'Map',
        xtype:'panel',
        html:'<div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 1300px"></div>',
        listeners:{
            resize: function(){
                var map = new ol.Map({
                    target: 'map',
                    layers: [
                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                        source: new ol.source.OSM()
                        })
                    ],
                    view: new ol.View({
                        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
                        zoom: 4
                    })
                });

            }
        }
```

Comment: It should be in `render` or `afterrender function` instead. In your implementation, the Map is created every time the window is resized.